# Test for noticing high quality answers while making review tasks can easily be guessed

Tags: bug, feature-request, review-audits

There are sometimes these tests, that check whether you are paying enough attention while reviewing. I noticed that when it checks whether you can **identify a high quality answer** it can easily be guessed.

As you can see on the screenshot below, it shows that there are **2 answers** to the question, and one is accepted. Still, in the **bottom part only one answer** is showed with 0 votes. Usually, when not testing, you can see other answers as well.

I don't know whether this is the intended behaviour, but I doubt. I can easily guess that this is a test without even reading the answer I should review.

My suggestion: in cases like that show 1, unaccepted answer at the top, so that this is consistent with the bottom part.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Seeing this reminds me of [Alignment/spacing issues in the review interface](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364415/alignment-spacing-issues-in-the-review-interface). Once you notice it, you can't un-see it.

Comment: the idea is that you pay attention to details, when you find super mission accomplished

Comment: The easier audits are to spot, the better IMO. If you don't spot really easy to identify audits then you are 100% definitely robo-reviewing.